# Removing an user from a user field? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, advanced-custom-fields

I am coding a 'favorite' system where an user can save a post as favorite. I've managed to get it to work with users being added to the list, but user getting removed from the list is not quite simple. Or well.. I can at least not find something on it. How do I remove an user from a user field in Advanced Custom Fields.

Tried unsetting the array, tried following some guides and tried to find something on the official docs about removing users. I must have overseen something.

This is what I have so far:

```
public function removefavorite_callback()
{
    $response['bSucces'] = false;
    $response['sMessage'] = __('Error, try again or contact an administrator.', 'language');
    $iCurrentUserID         = get_current_user_id();
    $oCurrentUser           = get_user_by('ID', $iCurrentUserID);

    $arr = array();
    $favoriteUsers = get_field('favorite_users', (int)$_POST['iHostingID']);


    foreach ($favoriteUsers as $fKey => $fUser) 
    {
        if($fUser->ID != $iCurrentUserID)
        {
            array_push($arr, $fUser->ID);
            update_field('favorite_users', $arr, (int)$_POST['iHostingID']);
        }
    }

$response['sMessage'] = __('Host removed from favorites.', 'language');
$response['bSucces'] = true;
echo json_encode($response);
wp_die();
}
```

And the jQuery if interested:

```
if(jQuery(oThis).hasClass('favorized'))
{
    if(jQuery('.hosting--card-favorite').attr('data-attr-postid') > 0)
    {
    var data = {
    action: 'ajax_hosting_remove_favorite',
    iHostingID: jQuery(oThis).attr('data-attr-postid'),
    }
```

So, If you got any ideas or tips on how removing that one single user via their ID from the user field, then I would greatly apreciate the help.

Comment: You should probably not try and update the field inside your foreach loop all the time, but once after.

Comment: @misorude Geez... That fixed it. Of course it did. Been working for way to long today, thanks tho! :)